# 4k Sectors: Which Drives Don't Lie About Having 512b Sectors and Correctly Report 4k Sectors?

Tags: windows, linux, hard-drive, sectors

I recently returned a Western Digital WD20EARS drive with 4k sectors (Western Digital refers to this as "advanced format"), because I found out that it lies and reports 512b sectors to the OS, and there's no way to disable this behavior (there's only a jumper to offset the LBA by one to align 512b sector 63 with a 4k sector).

Which drives on the market correctly report 4k sectors to the OS or have a jumper to do so?  I'm not asking about an LBA offset jumper, like Western Digital uses, since the drive is still lies to the OS when it's set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a 4K native (4Kn) drive, to my knowledge there are no drives on the market at the moment that support this, either by default or through a jumper.

Stick with the 512B native sector drives for now and avoid the 512 emulation (512e) drives.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps by:

"fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo c:"

And presumably that returned information similar to this to you:

Bytes per sector:                          512
Bytes per cluster:                         4096

Bytes per File Record Segment :          1024

Comment: This refers to partition, not disk.